# How to get Date only of TextBoxFor in MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code,

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfFileClosed, 
                   new {id="txtClosingDate", 
                   @class = "DataEntry_Date" } )%>
```

It gives me the DateTime like "03/12/2012 10:09:50 AM".
"DataOfFileClosed" is a property of DataTime type. I want to get the whole DateTime but for editing/viewing purpose I want only date "03/12/2012".

One thing that I don't want to use attribute over this property.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
@Html.TextBox("DateOfFileClosed", string.Format("{0:d}", Model.DateOfFileClosed), new {id="txtClosingDate", @class = "DataEntry_Date" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *DataAnnotations* in the Model.

```
[Display(Name = "File closed on:")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DateOfFileClosed { get; set; }
```

and use this in the View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfFileClosed)
```